# What's Mrs. Potts' first name?

Tags: beauty-and-the-beast, beauty-and-the-beast-2017

Yesterday I went to see the new Beauty and the Beast and it has been bugging me since then.

During the whole film she's called Mrs. Potts and when

> she's finally reunited with her husband, he calls her darling or another pet name (I don't exactly remember what, but it wasn't her name)

I've been looking around and found nothing, so if anyone know I'll be really grateful.

Comment: Are you asking what her *first* name is?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Will edit to clarify things D:

Comment: Tea. Or coffee.

Comment: @Verdan - I assumed it was gonna start with a T, but it doesn't. :-(

Comment: Clearly her first name is Missus.  ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Beatrice

> *He shouted happily, “Darling?”
>
>   Mrs. Potts smiled back. “Hello, Mr. Potts,” she said, running toward him.
>
>   **“Beatrice,** Chip,” he said as his wife and son fell into his arms. “I’ve found you.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Beauty and the Beast (2017): Official Novelization](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30145679-beauty-and-the-beast-novelization)</sup></sub>

This mention (in both the film and the film's novelisation) are the first time we've seen her name in any canon Disney media.

Answer (score -1):

In the cartoon version she's also referred to as Beatrice by the feather duster when she announces

> "Beatrice I saw a girl in the castle".

Comment: That's simply not correct. Babette's line is "***A girl,** I saw a girl in the castle".***

Answer (score -2):

During the reunion scene at the end of the live action I believe to have heard Mr. Potts call her "Midge", but I might be wrong.